# Tkinter Scrollbar Widget within frames

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I need to add a scrollbar to a frame that shall be alongside other frames within a window. I only want to add the scrollbar to that particular frame but I am having trouble with it. I have read about the need to use `tk.Canvas` to house the scrollbar widget but I am still getting it wrong.

[Picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mK1d.jpg). I would like the scrollbar only on the left frame.

Here is my example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()


        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(master, background="#ffffff",height=200,width=200)
        self.frame1.pack()

    def populate(self):
        '''Put in some fake data'''
        for row in range(100):
            tk.Label(self.frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", 
                     relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
            t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
            tk.Label(self.frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=1)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

root=tk.Tk()
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run your code I see the scrollbar, and your screenshot also shows a scrollbar. I don't see any problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I were you I would strongly suggest looking up the [Grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) layout manager for tkinter so you can specify what row and column you want a widget to be on exactly. You can even specify expanding and shrinking behaviour.

Comment: This seemed to be my problem. I have managed to to add the scrollbar successfully. Thank!